# error compiling Spirit sample

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, std-pair

The accepted answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4610937/how-to-put-results-into-a-stl-map-by-using-boost-spirit) other question lead me to [this](http://boost-spirit.com/home/articles/qi-example/parsing-a-list-of-key-value-pairs-using-spirit-qi/) sample, but compiling it give a long error list. Here the sample code, I added just the includes and a dummy main():

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

template <typename Iterator>
struct keys_and_values
  : qi::grammar<Iterator, std::map<std::string, std::string>()>
{
    keys_and_values()
      : keys_and_values::base_type(query)
    {
        query =  pair >> *((qi::lit(';') | '&') >> pair);
        pair  =  key >> -('=' >> value);
        key   =  qi::char_("a-zA-Z_") >> *qi::char_("a-zA-Z_0-9");
        value = +qi::char_("a-zA-Z_0-9");
    }
    qi::rule<Iterator, std::map<std::string, std::string>()> query;
    qi::rule<Iterator, std::pair<std::string, std::string>()> pair;
    qi::rule<Iterator, std::string()> key, value;
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::string input("key1=value1;key2;key3=value3");  // input to parse
    std::string::iterator begin = input.begin();
    std::string::iterator end = input.end();

    keys_and_values<std::string::iterator> p;    // create instance of parser
    std::map<std::string, std::string> m;        // map to receive results
    bool result = qi::parse(begin, end, p, m);   // returns true if successful
}
```

I've tried both boost 1.42 (default on my Ubuntu 11.04 distro), and 1.48 (downloaded). Errors (I report those filtered by QtCreator) differ: ver 1.42 gives

```
/usr/include/boost/fusion/support/tag_of.hpp:92:13: error: no matching function for call to ‘assertion_failed(mpl_::failed************ boost::mpl::not_<boost::fusion::detail::is_specialized<std::pair<std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char> > > >::************)’

/usr/include/boost/spirit/home/support/attributes.hpp:409: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::basic_string<char>::basic_string(std::pair<std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char> >&)’

/usr/include/boost/spirit/home/support/attributes.hpp:409: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::basic_string<char>::basic_string(mpl_::void_&)’
```

while ver. 1.48 gives

```
/home/carlo/Projects/spirit_vect_literals-build-desktop/../../cpp/boost_1_48_0/boost/spirit/home/qi/detail/assign_to.hpp:123: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::pair<std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char> >::pair(const std::basic_string<char>&)’
```

Do I have something missing?

**edit**: I've found the solution: add this header and both versions compile

```
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/std_pair.hpp>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Congratulations on tracking this down... I hit the same error a few weeks back and wasted hours with it. As you found, the solution is just to include this:

```
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/std_pair.hpp>
```

which provides the necessary magic for Qi to use std::pair as the output of a rule.

I'm mainly leaving this answer here just so the question no longer shows up as unanswered - if you want to add/accept your own answer I'll retract this.

Comment: yup that is a serious faq, though in fairness it is [a comment by Thomas Heller](http://boost-spirit.com/home/articles/qi-example/parsing-a-list-of-key-value-pairs-using-spirit-qi/comment-page-1/#comment-160) on that article :)

Comment: @sehe: I found that small line after pages and pages of heavy reading and many attempts (partly successful, but generally frustrating) of crafting my extra small test case. I cannot believe that **include** could solve my problem. What hurts me, it's that the docs hide the simplicity clearly illustrated by Hartmut Kaiser...

Comment: @chac Yeah, it's a shame that page is community maintained, or I'd personally edit the #include in there.